# Replace the values under some columns using awk or sed

Tags: awk, sed

I have a data, which contains some strange values under the columns start with "AS_".

It is a csv file, but for understanding I am putting the files with space,

```
sl no   AS_2f   AD_2f   SR_2f   SV_2f   AS_5f   AD_5f   SR_5f   SV_5f                                                   1.0     3.0     5.0     35.0    9.0     11.0    13.0    15.0    17.0
2.0     3.0     4.0     5.0     6.0     107.0   8.0     204.0   10.0
3.0     3.4     34.0    4.2     4.6     5.0     5.4     5.8     6.2
4.0     3.0     2.0     1.0     0.0     -1.0    -2.0    204.0   -4.0
5.0     24.5    44.0    63.5    83.0    102.5   122.0   141.5   161.0
6.0     32.0    58.0    84.0    110.0   136.0   162.0   188.0   214.0 

cat << EOF > data.csv
sl no,AS_2f,AD_2f,SR_2f,SV_2f,AS_5f,AD_5f,SR_5f,SV_5f
1.0,3.0,5.0,35.0,9.0,11.0,13.0,15.0,17.0
2.0,3.0,4.0,5.0,6.0,107.0,8.0,204.0,10.0
3.0,3.4,34.0,4.2,4.6,5.0,5.4,5.8,6.2
4.0,3.0,2.0,1.0,0.0,-1.0,-2.0,204.0,-4.0
5.0,24.5,44.0,63.5,83.0,102.5,122.0,141.5,161.0
6.0,32.0,58.0,84.0,110.0,136.0,162.0,188.0,214.0
EOF
```

I would like to replace the values with greater than 20 with "nan" under all "AS_" columns (AS_2f, AS_5f, AS_9f, etc.). There are many more AS_ columns.

I can do it for AS_2f only, I can't able to do it for other AS_ columns. My script is.

```
awk -F',' 'NR==1 {print} NR>1 {for(i=2; i<=NF; i++) if ($i > 20 && i==2) $i="nan"; print}' data.csv
```

Desire output:

```
sl no,AS_2f,AD_2f,SR_2f,SV_2f,AS_5f,AD_5f,SR_5f,SV_5f
1.0,3.0,5.0,35.0,9.0,11.0,13.0,15.0,17.0
2.0,3.0,4.0,5.0,6.0,nan,8.0,204.0,10.0
3.0,3.4,34.0,4.2,4.6,5.0,5.4,5.8,6.2
4.0,3.0,2.0,1.0,0.0,-1.0,-2.0,204.0,-4.0
5.0,nan,44.0,63.5,83.0,nan,122.0,141.5,161.0
6.0,nan,58.0,84.0,110.0,nan,162.0,188.0,214.0
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
awk '
    BEGIN { FS = OFS = "," }

    {
        # perform any substitutions
        # (does nothing when NR==1 because c is empty)
        for (i in c)
            if ($i>20)
                $i="nan"
    
        # apply OFS (optional if FS==OFS)
        $1=$1

        # output
        print
    }

    # save column numbers to check
    NR==1 {
        for (i=1; i<=NF; i++)
            if ($i~/^AS_/)
                c[i]
    }
' data.csv
```

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -E '1h;1b;G;s/$/\n/
        :a;s/^([^,\n]+,?)([^\n]*\n)([^,\n]+,?)([^\n]*\n.*)/\2\4\n\1,\3/;ta
        s/^([0-9]{3,}\..|[3-9].\..|2[^0]\..|20\.[^0]),+AS_.*/nan,/mg
        s/,.*/,/mg;s/\n//g;s/,$//' file
```

The main idea is to pair up each column with its heading and then substitute `nan` where the value of the column is above `20` and contains `AS_`.

Make a copy of the headings.

Append the copy to each line with an appended newline.

Pair up each column with its heading, separating value from heading by a comma.

Replace any value above `20` and whose heading contains `AS_` with `nan,`.

Remove any headings, newlines or introduced commas and print the result.

N.B. This assumes the input file is a csv file **not** as OP posted i.e. space separated.

Answer (score 1):

I would ameliorate

```
awk -F',' 'NR==1 {print} NR>1 {for(i=2; i<=NF; i++) if ($i > 20 && i==2) $i="nan"; print}' data.csv
```

following way, let `data.csv` content be

```
sl no,AS_2f,AD_2f,SR_2f,SV_2f,AS_5f,AD_5f,SR_5f,SV_5f
1.0,3.0,5.0,35.0,9.0,11.0,13.0,15.0,17.0
2.0,3.0,4.0,5.0,6.0,107.0,8.0,204.0,10.0
3.0,3.4,34.0,4.2,4.6,5.0,5.4,5.8,6.2
4.0,3.0,2.0,1.0,0.0,-1.0,-2.0,204.0,-4.0
5.0,24.5,44.0,63.5,83.0,102.5,122.0,141.5,161.0
6.0,32.0,58.0,84.0,110.0,136.0,162.0,188.0,214.0
```

then

```
awk 'BEGIN {FS=OFS=","} NR==1 {print; split($0, names)} NR>1 {for(i=2; i<=NF; i++) if ($i > 20 && index(names[i],"AS_")==1) $i="nan"; print}' data.csv
```

gives output

```
sl no,AS_2f,AD_2f,SR_2f,SV_2f,AS_5f,AD_5f,SR_5f,SV_5f
1.0,3.0,5.0,35.0,9.0,11.0,13.0,15.0,17.0
2.0,3.0,4.0,5.0,6.0,nan,8.0,204.0,10.0
3.0,3.4,34.0,4.2,4.6,5.0,5.4,5.8,6.2
4.0,3.0,2.0,1.0,0.0,-1.0,-2.0,204.0,-4.0
5.0,nan,44.0,63.5,83.0,nan,122.0,141.5,161.0
6.0,nan,58.0,84.0,110.0,nan,162.0,188.0,214.0
```

Explanation of changes made: I inform GNU `AWK` that `,` is both field separator (`FS`) and output field separator (`OFS`). I use [String Functions](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html) `split` and `index`. In 1st line I populate array `names` so `names[1]` is `sl no`, `names[2]` is `AS_2f`, `names[3]` is `AD_2f` and so on. For each column in each column I check if its' name start with `AS_` using `index` function and checking if it return 1, which mean `AS_` is at start.

*(tested in GNU Awk 5.1.0)*

Answer (score 1):

Here is a Ruby with the built-in CSV parser to do that:

```
ruby -r csv -e 'BEGIN{opts={:headers=>true, :converters => :numeric} }

tbl=CSV.parse($<.read, **opts)

tbl.headers.select{|col| col[/^AS_/] }.
    each{|hdr| tbl.by_col![hdr]=tbl.by_col[hdr].map{|v| v>20 ? "nan" : v} }

puts tbl' file
```

For an `awk` I would do:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}
FNR==1{ # get headers
    for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) if ($i~/^AS_/) c[i]
}

FNR>1 {for (e in c) if ($e>20) $e="nan"}
1' file
```

Either prints:

```
sl no,AS_2f,AD_2f,SR_2f,SV_2f,AS_5f,AD_5f,SR_5f,SV_5f
1.0,3.0,5.0,35.0,9.0,11.0,13.0,15.0,17.0
2.0,3.0,4.0,5.0,6.0,nan,8.0,204.0,10.0
3.0,3.4,34.0,4.2,4.6,5.0,5.4,5.8,6.2
4.0,3.0,2.0,1.0,0.0,-1.0,-2.0,204.0,-4.0
5.0,nan,44.0,63.5,83.0,nan,122.0,141.5,161.0
6.0,nan,58.0,84.0,110.0,nan,162.0,188.0,214.0
```